# UIActivityIndicator stopAnimating() not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

In my SignInViewController i have this code that adds the activity when a button is clicked and in my app delegate i run the stopanimating function when a fuction has finished, i know the function is running as i can get it to print out something but the activity indicator is not dissapearing

any help very appriciated quite new to swift so dumbed down answers appreciated

```
     @IBAction func googleSignInButton(_ sender: Any) {

            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()


            activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
            activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = 
            UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
            view.addSubview(activityIndicator)

            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()


        }

        func stopanimating() {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        }
```

Comment: are you calling `stopanimating()` on main thread?

Comment: im not sure what you mean by ui thread, you mean on this current view controller if so no im calling it in app delegate at the end of a function by calling    var sivc = SignInViewController() and then func() { .....   sivc.stopanimating }

Comment: @Ray is your function getting called.

Comment: function is definatly getting called as i added a print("is this running") and it appears in my log

Comment: @ray you can try to hide activity indicator at point you call that function. Does it stops rotating ?

Comment: no it is still animating (still spinning around)

Comment: @Ray at what point you want to stop animation?Where is start animation function?

Comment: have you read my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151195/discussion-between-tushar-sharma-and-ray).

Comment: @Ray see this it will help you clear what needs to be done-:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534199/calling-delegate-function-from-appdelegate-not-working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151208/discussion-between-tushar-sharma-and-ray).

Answer (score 4):

Try calling `stopanimating()` on main thread.

```
func stopanimating() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

Comment: its requires my to put self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating() but still does not get rid of the activity indicator

Comment: Not on your original problem, but fyi on your comment about "self": It requires you to put "self.activityIndicator..." there, because Swift wants you to understand, that as soon as you are referencing that variable inside of your closure {...}, this may result in a reference cycle.

Comment: Do you have an outlet from your "activityIndicator" to your SignInViewController() class? It is not visible in your code you posted above, so it might be possible that you are just instantiating a new object of type ActivityIndicator.

Comment: @Ray try to call google delegate function that check for successful login in viewController and perform stop animation  it will work.