# Calling delegate function from AppDelegate not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, delegates

I am trying to call delegate function in AppDelegate, but seems like it never get invoked.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,appdelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if let navigationController = window?.rootViewController, let
            viewController = navigationController.childViewControllers.first as? ViewController {
            viewController.delegate = self
        }
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func callfromDelegte(indicator: UIActivityIndicatorView) {
        indicator.stopAnimating()
    }
```

**ViewController-:**

```
import UIKit

protocol appdelegate:class {
    func callfromDelegte(indicator:UIActivityIndicatorView)
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var indicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
   weak var delegate:appdelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        indicator.startAnimating()
        indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    }

    @IBAction func rotateAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if delegate != nil{
        delegate?.callfromDelegte(indicator: indicator)
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Delegate is always nil, it never goes inside function. What is that i don't
now about delegates yet? How does Google **GIDSignInDelegate** and its delegate functions get called inside AppDelegate from controller class? I know it might be very stupid question but I would still like to know.Thanks

Ok it worked as i have not embeded my controller with navigationController. So it was not going inside **if let**. It worked simply like this-:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
//        if let navigationController = window?.rootViewController, let
//            viewController = navigationController.childViewControllers.first as? ViewController {
//            viewController.delegate = self
//        }
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let controller = window?.rootViewController as! ViewController
        controller.delegate = self
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create the `Viewcontroller` object directly and set the `delegate` inside your `app delegate`. You need to access the `Viewcontroller` object first because it is the inside the `rootViewController` so you need to implement like this

```
if let navigationController = window?.rootViewController, let 
   viewController = navigationController.childViewControllers.first as? ViewController {
 viewController.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: still nil I updated code.Issue now is it is not going inside if let .

Comment: @TusharSharma, I can see the delegate value and it is not nil for me

Comment: The ViewController class where did you define inside your storyboard? Is it inside the Main.storyboard?

Comment: You can also try the Woof approach. If you do not want to make the customdelegate.

Comment: you were right I need to access controller . I was not using navigation controller though.

Comment: Cool, it helps:)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get AppDelegate instance from shared application. Hope it will help

This is Swift 3

```
@IBAction func rotateAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

        delegate?.callfromDelegte(indicator: indicator)
}
```